# Which comic first shows how Superman built his "Fortress of Solitude"?

Tags: dc, superman, episode-identification

Can anyone tell me which classic Superman comic (from the 60s & 70s) was the very first time that showed how Superman built the Fortress of Solitude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, that would be [Superman #176](http://comiccoverage.typepad.com/comic_coverage/fortress_at_50/index.html) from 1964 in which we see Superman constructing his "Fortress of Solitude" with his bare hands from the side of a mountain on the outskirts of Metropolis.

[image]

Note that before this one, he'd already had [several other hideaways](http://comiccoverage.typepad.com/comic_coverage/2008/03/the-fortress--6.html) including an Arctic Citadel, a meteor base and an undersea fortress which we see him constructing in [Action Comic #144](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_244) from 1958.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. The "Artic Citadel" sounds more like the Fortress of Solitude we all know and love. I'll have to look that one up.